# Отладка на устройстве Apple

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift

Вышел *Xcode 7.0.1*.

В описании написано:

> Now you can go beyond the simulator to test your app on an iPad, iPhone, or Apple Watch — for free. Simply enter your Apple ID into the Accounts preference pane, then attach a device to your Mac using a Lightning cable. You can use the same Apple ID you already use for iCloud, iTunes, or the App Store, or create a new one. Join the Apple Developer Program when you’re ready to distribute or submit your apps to the App Store.

Насколько я понял, тут написано, что теперь для отладки на устройстве подходит обычный аккаунт (*Apple ID*), аккаунт разработчика нужен только для размещения в *App Store*.

Но у меня не получается, выдает ошибку:

> No non–expired provisioning profiles were found.
>
> Xcode can attempt to fix this issue. 
>   This will reset your code signing and provisioning settings to recommended values and resolve issues with signing identities and provisioning profiles.

Нажимаешь кнопку исправить, но не исправляется.

Как быть?

Answer (score 1):

Все оказалось очень просто.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Надо нажать вот эту кнопку, после этого все прекрасно запускается на устройстве!